# Refit API HTTPPost 'Unexpected character encountered while parsing value' from .net Core 3.0 Console app

Tags: c#, api, .net-core, refit

I have an api endpoint as follows

```
    [HttpPost("create")]
    [MapToApiVersion("1.0")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Post(CarDto carDto)
    {
        return Ok(await _carService.CreateCarAsync(carDto));
    }
```

The Dto below is a shared do in nuget package with contracts

```
public class CarDto
{
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "Id")]
    public string Id { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "Colour")]
    public string Colour{ get; set; }
}
```

My calling code in the Console app

```
public interface ICarServiceApi
{
    [Post("/Cars/create")]
    Task<bool> CreateCar(CarDto carDto);
}

var carServiceApi = RestService.For<ICarServiceApi>("https://localhost:5001/api/v1");
var car = new CarDto {Id ="123", Colour = "Red"};

await carServiceApi.CreateCar(car);
```

The exception i get is as follows

> Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: {. Path '', line
>   1, position 1.

The call to the Http get works fine so something is wrong in my setup above

Comment: any clues? have same error - but JSON response seems fine

Comment: What type does `_carService.CreateCarAsync` return?

Comment: I'm having the same error, and I'm done with this issue.
Moving to another approach in 3, 2, 1 ...